Usage of 舟 in this context?

I'm a bit stumbled on why he's using 舟 here. 22のカラ舟が積み上げる is this a way of saying? If I had to guess it may  be related to how much he can eat in the context?  Give the other character is a 18舟

Takoyaki use [船皿]【ふなざら】 or alternatively, 舟皿{ふなざら} as their dish. Note the resemblance of its shape to that of a ship. So in this case, the comic is shortening 舟皿 to just 舟, and is simply counting how many plates the competitors have gone through.
